# Help with Apex Test Class I have Written

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a trigger and I have also written a test class to test the trigger but only 20% of the trigger code is covered leaving 134 lines uncovered. My overall coverage is 60% and I'm trying to increase the coverage to 75%.

I am posting the trigger and the test class I've written. Can someone please help me.

**TRIGGER**

```
trigger ShowingNotesAdded on pb__Showing__c (after insert, before update) {
Account[] a = new Account[6];
pb__InventoryItem__c[] i = new pb__InventoryItem__c[6];
integer index = 0;
integer c = 0;
string response;
Recordtype r;
Date duedate;
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {};
for (pb__Showing__c s : trigger.new){
    //r = [select name from recordtype where sobjecttype = 'pb__Showing__c' and id = :s.RecordTypeId];


   if(trigger.IsInsert){

        response = s.record_type_name__c;
        if (response.contains('Lettings')){
            r = [select id, Name from recordtype where sobjecttype = 'Event' and Name = 'Lettings Viewing'];
        }
        if (response.contains('Sales')){
            r = [select id, Name from recordtype where sobjecttype = 'Event' and Name = 'Sales Viewing'];
        }  
        if (response.contains('Lease')){
            r = [select id, Name from recordtype where sobjecttype = 'Event' and Name = 'Lease Viewing'];
        }  

        Event e = new Event();
        e.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
        e.Subject = r.Name;
        e.RecordTypeId = r.Id;
        e.Description = 'Event created through Showing/Viewing';
        e.WhatId = s.Id;
        e.StartDateTime = s.start_time__c;
        e.EndDateTime = s.end_time__c;
        insert e;
  }


    if (trigger.IsUpdate){
        pb__Showing__c olds = Trigger.oldMap.get(s.ID);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        //create date from datetime
        duedate = Date.newInstance(s.Start_Time__c.year(),s.Start_Time__c.month(),s.Start_Time__c.day());

        if (s.pb__Inventory__c != null && s.Inventory_A_Notes__c != null && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_A__c != false ){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.pb__Inventory__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name, PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear ');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }    
            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
            t.Description = s.Inventory_A_Notes__c;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.Status = 'Completed';

            insert t;
            index++;
        }

       if (s.Inventory_B__c != null && s.Inventory_B_Notes__c != null  && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_B__c != false ){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_B__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name,PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear ');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }
            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
            t.Description = s.Inventory_B_Notes__c;
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.Status = 'Completed';

            insert t;
            index++;
        }

        if (s.Inventory_C__c != null && s.Inventory_C_Notes__c != olds.Inventory_C_Notes__c && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_C__c != false ){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_C__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name,PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }
            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.Description = s.Inventory_C_Notes__c;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.Status = 'Completed';

            insert t;
            index++;
        }

        if (s.Inventory_D__c != null && s.Inventory_D_Notes__c != olds.Inventory_D_Notes__c && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_D__c != false ){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_D__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name,PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }
            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
            t.Description = s.Inventory_D_Notes__c;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.Status = 'Completed';

            insert t;
            index++;
        }

        if (s.Inventory_E__c != null && s.Inventory_E_Notes__c != olds.Inventory_E_Notes__c && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_E__c != false){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_E__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name,PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }
           Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.Description = s.Inventory_E_Notes__c;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.Status = 'Completed';

            insert t;
            index++;
        }

        if (s.Inventory_F__c != null && s.Inventory_F_Notes__c != olds.Inventory_F_Notes__c && s.Send_Feedback_to_Vendor_F__c != false){
            toAddresses.clear();
            i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_F__c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name,PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

            mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear');
            toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
            mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            catch(System.EmailException ex){
                system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
                response = ex.getMessage();
            }

            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
            t.Subject = 'Lettings Viewing Feedback';
            t.Description = s.Inventory_F_Notes__c;
            t.ActivityDate = duedate;
            t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
            t.Status = 'Completed';
            insert t;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Test Class for the trigger**

@isTest
private class UnitTestShowingNotesAdded {

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    // TO DO: implement unit test




    User u = [select id from user where Name = 'Benjamin Smith'];

    //create test account
    Account a = new Account();
    a.LastName = 'testabcdef';
    a.PersonEmail='test@testsnk.com';
    a.Phone='987654';
    a.OwnerId = u.id;
    a.service_breach__c = false;
    a.pb__Status__c = 'Unqualified';
    insert a;

   pb__InventoryItem__c inv = new pb__InventoryItem__c();
    inv.name = 'abc123';
    inv.pb__IsForSale__c = true;
    inv.pb__PurchaseListPrice__c = 12313;
    inv.pb__IsAvailable__c = true;
    inv.Project__c = 'abcdd';
    inv.pb__ItemStatus__c = 'Available';
    inv.pb__IsBlocked__c = false;
    inv.SellerId__c = a.id;
    inv.AreaUAE__c = 'Dubai Marina';
    inv.Unit_No__c = '12test';
    inv.ItemStage__c = 'Available';
    insert inv;


   inv.OwnerId = u.id;
   update inv;

   //B

   pb__InventoryItem__c inv1 = new pb__InventoryItem__c();
    inv1.name = 'abc123';
    inv1.pb__IsForSale__c = true;
    inv1.pb__PurchaseListPrice__c = 12313;
    inv1.pb__IsAvailable__c = true;
    inv1.Project__c = 'abcdd';
    inv1.pb__ItemStatus__c = 'Available';
    inv1.pb__IsBlocked__c = false;
    inv1.SellerId__c = a.id;
    inv1.AreaUAE__c = 'Dubai Marina';
    inv1.Unit_No__c = '12test';
    inv1.ItemStage__c = 'Available';
    insert inv1;


   inv1.OwnerId = u.id;
   update inv1;


   pb__InventoryItem__c inv2 = new pb__InventoryItem__c();
    inv2.name = 'abc123';
    inv2.pb__IsForSale__c = true;
    inv2.pb__PurchaseListPrice__c = 12313;
    inv2.pb__IsAvailable__c = true;
    inv2.Project__c = 'abcdd';
    inv2.pb__ItemStatus__c = 'Available';
    inv2.pb__IsBlocked__c = false;
    inv2.SellerId__c = a.id;
    inv2.AreaUAE__c = 'Dubai Marina';
    inv2.Unit_No__c = '12test';
    inv2.ItemStage__c = 'Available';
    insert inv2;


   inv2.OwnerId = u.id;
   update inv2;

   Datetime todays= datetime.now();

     pb__Showing__c s = new pb__Showing__c();
     s.Start_Time__c=todays;
     s.End_Time__c=todays.addHours(2);
     s.Account__c=a.id;
     s.pb__Inventory__c=inv2.id;
     s.Status__c = 'Pending';
     insert s;




}
```

}

**THIS IS THE CODE THAT ISN'T BEING COVERED.**

i[index] = [select id, Unit_No_*c, AreaUAE*_c, Project_*c, sellerid*_c from pb_*InventoryItem*_c where id =: s.pb_*Inventory*_c];
            a[index] = [select Id, Name, PersonEmail from Account where Id =: i[index].SellerId__c];

```
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear ');
        toAddresses.add(a[index].PersonEmail);
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);                             
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Smith & Ken');                           
        mail.setSubject('Viewing Feedback');

        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }
        catch(System.EmailException ex){
            system.debug('============== email exception caught!!!=============');
            response = ex.getMessage();
        }    
        Task t = new Task();
        t.OwnerId = s.OwnerId;
        t.Subject = 'Viewing Feedback';
        t.Description = s.Inventory_A_Notes__c;
        t.WhatId = i[index].Id;
        t.ActivityDate = duedate;
        t.Status = 'Completed';

        insert t;
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Could you at the very least indicate what is not covered and what you suspect to be the problem ?

Comment: Hi Mate, the query to send the email and create a task is not being covered from  LINE i[index] = [select id, Unit_No__c, AreaUAE__c, Project__c, sellerid__c from pb__InventoryItem__c where id =: s.Inventory_B__c];

Comment: Hi Mate, I have added the code which isn't getting covered to the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The trigger is set to fire on after Insert and before Update, in your test class you look to be only calling an Insert on your pb__*Showing*_c object therefore the lines wrapped in the `if (trigger.IsUpdate)
{
}` section will not get covered by this test.

To gain any coverage in this section you will need to write test code to call an Update on a pb_*Showing*_c object.